# Initializing objects in storyboard programmatically with objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, initialization

I have an `UIImageView` object in one of my `viewController` view that is preloaded with a picture of the wheel. However, the rotation of the wheel is determined by the time of day. So when the program launches, I like the wheel to be initialized by the correct rotation base on the current time. I tried to do this with a rotation in the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller. While this works, one can visibly see the initial position and the switch to new position based on time.

I like the initialization to be invisible, that is the initialization to occur before the view is loaded. Where should I do that?

Comment: Is the initialization of the wheel happening asynchronously? Adding some code would be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I like the initialization to be invisible, that is the initialization
>   to occur before the view is loaded. Where should I do that?

A view controller's view will be loaded whenever the controller's `view` property is accessed, and `-viewDidLoad` will be called at that point. Putting your code to set up the view in `-viewDidLoad` is the correct thing to do. You can't initialize the view before it's loaded because it doesn't exist *until* it's loaded, but you should be able to set it up before it's displayed.

If you're not doing anything in your `-viewDidLoad` that would cause the wheel setup to be deferred to a later point in time, then you might try to load the view controller's view a little earlier. For example, you could implement `-prepareForSegue:sender:` in your view controller so that it accesses the `view` property, which will cause the view to be loaded.

Comment: Do you just access the view in a redundant line of code to force it to load? Is that acceptable? UI objects in the destination VC not being available in prepareForSegue have been annoying me, I didn't realise it was that easy to get them available!

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom class inherited from UIView and set some custom inits (in your case set a rotation transform) in didMoveToWindow method.